# Nautilus, Synaptic and System Settings crash after kernel version 3.0.0-18-generic installed

Tags: nautilus, kernel

On both my laptops I am getting regular crashes of Nautilus, Synaptic and System Settings after an upgrade to kernel 3.0.0-18-generic. As usual, I deleted 3.0.0.17 to save space on my drive -- that was pretty dumb.

Any ideas on why this might be? I guess each application might share similar code.

edit: dmesg gives this after synaptic crashed:

```
[ 4894.155206] synaptic[3944] general protection ip:102dbd7 sp:bfa2bdec error:0 in libc-2.13.so[fce000+178000]
```

Is libc-2.13.so module in the new kernel the problem?

Another crash: dmesg reports

```
[ 4894.155206] synaptic[3944] general protection ip:102dbd7 sp:bfa2bdec error:0 in libc-2.13.so[fce000+178000]
[ 5366.421289] synaptic[3979] general protection ip:ff9bd7 sp:bf9b00dc error:0 in libc-2.13.so[f9a000+178000]
[ 6994.829449] synaptic[4687] general protection ip:1c0bbd7 sp:bfbbde9c error:0 in libc-2.13.so[1bac000+178000]
```

Comment: libc6 (that's the package responsible for the libc-2.13.so file) is the C runtime library. You could perform a memory test (hold Shift when booting)

Comment: Thanks, but this has happened on two laptops today, highly coincidental to be memory-related.

Comment: What packages have been upgraded except for the kernel? You can check /var/log/apt/history.log for that (new messages are appended on the bottom)

Answer (score 2):

Similar issues reported about 3.0.0.18 at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/972821